# Can't install ubuntu error [ok] started dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd

Tags: boot, lenovo

I'm trying to install Ubunto on my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 310). I have put the Iso of ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64 on my bootable USB flash. After boot, It checks the disk for any error and found nothing but then the installation process freezes and the last line is:

[ok] Started dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.ce....shots. changes.pp link was shot down.

[image]

I attached the image of the frozen status. Currently, I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop and I want to install Ubuntu instead, and previously I had Ubuntu 18 installed on my laptop beside my Windows and had no problem installing it but after a while I removed it.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem and install Ubuntu?

Comment: Try booting with *Safe graphics* mode.

Comment: How should I do that? And won't it cause a problem in the future?

Comment: you have to choose [corresponding line of the bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPj30.png) and boot installer using it. During installation you have to install 3rd party drivers, or install Nvidia drivers on the installed system by `software-properties-gtk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @N0rbert I found the answer. I should boot the system in safe graphic mode.